# How to store a series of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, storage

I'm working on a fifteen puzzle, and trying to store the different states of the board as I move the tiles.

Since I will be attempting to set up the puzzle with a IDFS/IDFSA* search algorithm, I need a way to store each array.

This is all very new to me, and I would LOVE some pointers on how to do this. Can link code if necessary on what I have to base this on. Thanks for anything you can help me with, I'm lost!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged C++, so I assume you want an answer in that language.  You can use the following type to store board state:

```
typedef array<array<int, 4>, 4> BoardState;
```

This is a 4x4 "matrix" of integers.  I would have 0 meaning empty and some other n (1 <= n <= 15) meaning that the nth piece is at the position.

For an A* search you just needed to spot a good heuristic, for example total manhattan distance of pieces from final position.  After that it's just a simple textbook implementation.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search

Answer (score 0):

Ok for the boardstate:

```
typedef std::array<std::array<int 5>, 5> boardstate;
```

and hold the entire series:

```
std::vector< boardstate > timeseries;
```

you can add elements in the series just as with any other element vector at the time you like

```
int t;
boardstate currentstate;

timeseries[t]=currentstate;
```